# Get the highest and lowest values of a certain attribute in jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="2" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div id="5" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div id="3" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div id="1" class="maindiv">test</div> 
<div class="maindiv">test</div>     
<div id="4" class="maindiv">test</div>
```

How to get the highest id (5) and the lowest id (1) in jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: `document.getElementById();`?

Comment: Which attribute in your case?

Comment: Hm, I don't think those ids there are even valid. Either way: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @Mahn they are valid.  The only restriction on `id` is that it cannot contain spaces.

Comment: @ExplosionPills afaik an id cannot begin with a number

Comment: @Mahn you don't know far enough: http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global

Comment: @ExplosionPills ah, I guess it got more permissive with the html5 spec then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function minMaxId(selector) {
  var min=null, max=null;
  $(selector).each(function() {
    var id = parseInt(this.id, 10);
    if ((min===null) || (id < min)) { min = id; }
    if ((max===null) || (id > max)) { max = id; }
  });
  return {min:min, max:max};
}

minMaxId('div'); // => {min:1, max:5}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qQvVQ/

Answer (score 23):

To achieve this you can create an array containing all the `id` values, then use `Math` to get the highest/lowest:

```js
var ids = $('.maindiv[id]').map((i, el) => parseInt(el.id, 10)).get();
var lowest = Math.min.apply(Math, ids); // = 1
var highest = Math.max.apply(Math, ids); // = 5

console.log(`${lowest} => ${highest}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="2" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div id="5" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div id="3" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div id="1" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div class="maindiv">test</div>
<div id="4" class="maindiv">test</div>
```

Note the `[id]` attribute selector is required, otherwise `0` is assumed for the missing value.

If you need IE support, you need to use an anonymous function instead of the arrow function:

```
var ids = $(".maindiv[id]").map(function() {
  return parseInt(this.id, 10);
}).get();
```

Comment: 12 seconds slower than me, but with an example, so +1!

Comment: That's what I call a _deep understanding of both JavaScript and jQuery_.

Comment: It is a fine solution but some might gripe about the use of globals and the unnecessary two passes through the list when min/max can be determined in one pass.

Comment: Most if not all answers are perfect but i'm choosing for being most forward...thanks :)

Comment: Now there is a problem...if an id is not a number this will return "NaN"

Comment: @MichaelSamuel that's a simple solution, use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` around `this.id`, or simply check for `isNaN` to disregard the value.

Comment: can you edit the example or illustrate more as I can't understand what you mean...thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel I've updated to use `parseInt` so that values will be converted to numeric. If this still doesn't fix your issues you would be best to start a new question

Comment: Excelent answer!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var min = Number.MAX_VALUE, max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
$(".maindiv").each(function () {
    var id = parseInt(this.id, 10);
    if (id > max) {
        max = id;
    }
    if (id < min) {
        min = id;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable and compare it to each element using `Math.max` inside a loop.

```
var maxval = Number.MIN_VALUE,
    minval = Number.MAX_VALUE;

$('div').each(function () {
    var num = parseInt(this.id, 10) || 0; // always use a radix
    maxval = Math.max(num, maxval);
    minval = Math.min(num, minval);
});

console.log('max=' + maxval);
console.log('min=' + minval);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gCADe/

Answer (score 1):

You should use data instead of id for this.

```
<div data-value="2" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-value="5" class="maindiv">test</div>
<div data-value="3" class="maindiv">test</div>
etc.
```

Edit: I shortened my answer in favour of Rory McCrossan's accepted answer above.

Comment: Well id can be used, but data is more appropriate. As you mentioned in your question these are values. Ids are intended to be used as identifiers and not as values.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel because an ID is not supposed to store data but data-* attributes are. So, using the data attribute is a better choice.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly How would you implement the usage of data-* to Rory McCrossan answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
var valArray = [];
$('.maindiv').each(function(){
    valArray.push(parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10));
})
valArray.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b })

valArrayp[0] // lowest
valArrayp[valArrayp.length - 1] // highest`
```

Have not tested, should work though

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sort function to do it.

```
function arrayify(obj){
    return [].slice.call(null,obj);
}
var all = arrayify(document.querySelectorAll('div[id]'));
var max = all.sort().pop();
var min = all.sort().reverse().pop();
```

This is way easier that using jQuery