# jquery - get element with the highest attribut value

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

How can I do to get the element with the attribut name equal to 'temp' and with the highest attribut value?

**XML**

```
<el>
   <em name="temp" value="5">
      <data>nok</data>
   </em>
   <em name="other" value="10">
      <data>nok</data>
   </em>
   <em name="temp" value="8">
      <data>ok</data>
   </em>
</el>
```

The actual code that I have:

**JQUERY**

```
var name= 'temp';

$xml.find("em[name=" + name + "]").each(function() {
    $(this).find( "data" ).each(
        function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        } 
    );                             
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var valArray = [];
 $xml.find('em[name=temp]').each(function(){
   valArray.push(parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10));
 })
 valArray.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b })

 valArray[0] // lowest
 valArray[valArray.length - 1] // highest`
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5UZXL/7/)**

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776142/1719752)**

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post because I only want to get the element with attribut name equal to 'temp'. Then I want to have as a return the element to be parsed also.

Comment: @Jils:i have updated for getting for name=temp. what else you want.

Comment: That's work in my real code , thanks. There is a way the get the corresponding 'em' element something like $em?

Comment: store $(this) in array rather than $(this).attr('value'). and then you can access it as valArray[i]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, comments speak for themselves I hope ...

```
 // var for the highest value
 var highestval = 0;

 // the element we are seeking
 var highestvalelement;

 // loop through the em elements
 $xml.find("em[name=" + name +"]").each(
    function()
    {
       // the value attribute of this element
       elval = $(this).attr('id')

       // is it the highest
       if(elval >= highestval)
       {
           // set the highest value
           highestval = elval;

           // store the object
           highestvalelement = $(this);
       }         
    }
 );

 // highestvalelement will contain the em elemnt with the highest value
```

Comment: Its also correct but I think the solution of @Milind is better in term of performance...I don't know actually :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var name= 'temp';
$xml.find("em[name=" + name + "]").each(function() {
$(this).find( "data" ).each(function(){
                                    alert($(this).innerhtml());
                                 });   
});
```

And for better answer please tell us error.......

Comment: there is no error, I juste didn't find the solution to have what I want.