# How to addClass to div with largest data-attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the largest or smallest value from data attributes, and add a class to the div with the largest or smallest found value?

HTML output:

```
<div data-foo="12"></div>
<div data-foo="43"></div>
<div data-foo="3"></div>
<div data-foo="44"></div>
<div data-foo="153" class="yellow"></div>
```

.addClass("yellow");

I found this stackoverflow question which does help with finding the max or min's, but how apply a class to the div from which this value comes from?

[Get the highest and lowest values of a certain attribute in jQuery or Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775921/get-the-highest-and-lowest-values-of-a-certain-attribute-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var max = 0;
    $('div').attr("data-foo", function(i,val){
       max = +val > max ? +val : max;
    });
   $("div[data-foo='" + max + "']").addClass("yellow");// this is what you need to add class.do same process for min also if you required.
    console.log(max);
//for min 

var min = max;
    $('div').attr("data-foo", function(i,v){
       min = +v < min ? +v : min;
    });
    $("div[data-foo='" + min + "']").addClass("red");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-foo="12"></div>
<div data-foo="43"></div>
<div data-foo="3"></div>
<div data-foo="44"></div>
<div data-foo="153"></div>
```

Comment: it should work see if you are getting any error . it should apply on 3 and give <div class="yellow" data-foo="3"> working fine for me.

Comment: This doesn't work properly because in JavaScript `"44" > "143"` is `true` when comparing strings. Also, you're mixing in external state, using the `.attr` setter needlessly, and doing a `"[data-foo='" + min + "']"` lookup when that element is already in memory. See my answer for a better approach

Comment: @naomik i think +v will convert it in int so the current code will work properly.show me any use case if you have.

Comment: @SuchitKumar, ah sorry, I missed the unary operator you used there. Still, my other grievances about your solution are valid.

Comment: @SuchitKumar no, there's no reason to be calling the `.attr` setter or re-lookup elements that are already in memory. This is a very roundabout solution and I would discourage anyone from using it.

Comment: @SuchitKumar I provided an answer to the question too. Please view the code there. It's by no means perfect, but it's decent considering the limitations of how jQuery let's us manipulate the data.

Comment: @SuchitKumar `min` and `max` are still external [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)#Program_state);  You're using [.attr setter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) with an `undefined` return value; luckily jQuery ignores this otherwise you'd actually be deleting the `data-foo` values. You're still doing a new look-up with `$("div[data-foo='" + max + "']")` even though `$("div")` already contains the element we want to affect.

Comment: @SuchitKumar My answer does not have state, does not call the `.attr` setter function (because we're not setting any values...), and it does not re-lookup elements that we already queried.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function minMaxId(selector) {
  var min = null,
    max = null;
  $(selector).each(function() {
    var id = parseInt($(this).data('foo'), 10);
    if ((min === null) || (id < min)) {
      min = id;
    }
    if ((max === null) || (id > max)) {
      max = id;
    }
  });
  return {
    min: min,
    max: max
  };
}

// Returns Obj with min and max
minMaxId('div'); // => {min:1, max:5}

// Set a span with the values
$('#tmpMin').html(minMaxId('div').min)
$('#tmpMax').html(minMaxId('div').max)

// Change the highest one to have the class yellow
$('[data-foo=' + minMaxId('div').max + ']').addClass('yellow')

// Change the lowest one to have the class grey
$('[data-foo=' + minMaxId('div').min + ']').addClass('grey')
```

```css
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  }

.grey {
  background: grey;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-foo="12">Div 1</div>
<div data-foo="43">Div 2</div>
<div data-foo="3">Div 3</div>
<div data-foo="44">Div 4</div>
<div data-foo="153">Div 5</div>

Min: <span id="tmpMin"></span> || Max: <span id="tmpMax"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you'd want to close off your DIV tags.
Next, you can use the index of the element to highlight it eg.

```
$('div').eq(divIndex).addClass('yellow');
```

To get the divIndex, you just need to iterate through the list and perform a min/max search like so:

```
loop {
  if(curValue > value){
    value = curValue;
  }
}
```

See the full thing here on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/f2t1a5e2/